# How could I make a cell contain an entire array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to make a cell equal to an entire array in Google Apps Script and Google Sheets.

I have tried making the cell.setValue(array) but using this method the cell is equal to the first array item only.

```
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("A1").getValues();
var array = ["Item one", "Item two", "Item three"];
cell.setValue(array)
```

I want the cell to equal "Item one, Item two, Item three" but the cell equals to "Item one" using that method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the array to a string beforehand with [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
cell.setValue(array.join(", "));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toString()`

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 'a', '1a'];

console.log(array1.toString());
// output: "1,2,a,1a"
```

From: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/toString